# CREATE TRIGGER With Condition in Derby

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, derby

I have to write a sql update trigger statement for Apache Derby. I am usually working with Sql Server and T-SQL. But now I have to use Derby. Unfortunately I am very new to Derby and I couldn't find a proper solution in the Derby manual.

My Problem is that I have to check for a condition in the update trigger and based on the result of this condition I would do either an UPDATE or an INSERT, so in T-SQL I would use an IF-ELSE-condition. Can somebody tell me what the equivalent is in Derby or an alternative way? I already considered the WHEN-clause, but this seems the wrong direction.

I have following code till now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATE_EVENTS
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON ACCIDENTS
    REFERENCING OLD AS oldRow NEW AS newRow
    FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL

-- In the following, I would usually use an IF-ELSE Statement, 
-- but I can't use this in Derby. So I tried the optional WHEN Statement, 
-- but there I could not have an else "path", right?

-- This should be the If-Case
    WHEN((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VIEW_EVENTS WHERE ID_DATE = newRow.ID_DATE) > 0)
        UPDATE VIEW_EVENTS
        SET    DETAILS = newRow.DETAILS,
               PARTICIPANTS = newRow.PARTICIPANTS
        WHERE  ID_DATE = newRow.ID_DATE

-- And this should be the else case
    WHEN((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VIEW_EVENTS WHERE ID_DATE = newRow.ID_DATE) <= 0)
            INSERT INTO VIEW_EVENTS
            ( ID_KEY,
              ID_DATE,
              DETAILS,
              PARTICIPANTS
            )
            VALUES
            ( newRow.ID_KEY,
              newRow.ID_DATE,
              newRow.DETAILS,
              newRow.PARTICIPANTS
            );
```

This Statement is just a mini example to show you my problem. I hope you can help me :).

Best regards,

Yalcin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not tag indiscriminately. Your question has nothing to do with sql server.

But it seems that your goal is not directly achievable - as has been discussed (did you search?) [here](http://apache-database.10148.n7.nabble.com/Trigger-questions-td136172.html). Derby does not support multi-statement triggers. It seems that you need to use multiple triggers.